# How to turn a string of ints into a list of ints?

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, integer

Say you have this string of ints:

```
5125458993327395245 1108328029959651534 6552608174082565141 3081501567273068441 2414768202934775086
```

I tried using the string `join()` or the `list()` method but it separates each number into a single digit:

`['5', '1', '2', '5', '4', '5', '8', '9', '9', '3', '3', '2', '7', '3', '9', '5', '2', '4', '5']` etc.

How could one make a list that is composed of each elements e.g. each number separated by a space? Here the size of each digit is 19. Like so:

```
[5125458993327395245, 1108328029959651534, 6552608174082565141, 3081501567273068441, 2414768202934775086]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map with split

```
s = '5125458993327395245 1108328029959651534 6552608174082565141 3081501567273068441 2414768202934775086'
lst = list(map(int, s.split()))

[5125458993327395245,
 1108328029959651534,
 6552608174082565141,
 3081501567273068441,
 2414768202934775086]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example_string = "5125458993327395245 1108328029959651534 6552608174082565141 3081501567273068441 2414768202934775086"
example_list = []


for number in example_string.split(" "):
    example_list.append(number)

print(example_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is using **map()** function.

```
string_to_integer = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(string_to_integer)
```